# How to call a angular controller kept in another file from a mvc partial view

Tags: angularjs

Edit:- My project that is mvc-4 having lay out page that holds angular.js and bootstrap.js, bootstrap.js and the angularmodule.js. the layout is wrapped into the index page. For the first time in the left section all categories are loaded in the index page. When i click on the any category a partial page that has got all products are loaded in to the middle section of index. Now when i again click on the any of middle section product button that comes with all the product spectic customization returning a partial _customization page that is to load in the model pop up. so the below code is kept on the _customization partial page.

I have created some ng-controler.js file
that holds the following code

```
EposApp.controller("cntrlCustomization", function ($scope, getCustomization) {
    $scope.ListCollection = getCustomization.customization;
    $scope.total = 0;
    $scope.chkUnchk = function (v) {
        if (v.selectionState == 0) { v.selectionState = 1 }
      some more code...
    }
```

I have a _customization partial view in mvc with the following code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ngController/ngController.js"></script>


<script>
    var customizationJson = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(customizationJson));
        EposApp.factory('getCustomization', function () {
        return {
            customization: customizationJson
             }
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that the Epos.Contoller not getting called, although when i keep controller code direct to the partial view itseld it works fine.. could some body please help me with this whats the problem.

Comment: I bet the issue is that your module "EposApp" is not defined when you include ng-controller.js

Comment: see i have included the module script at the layout page for the index page.

Comment: Please help me with this i am toiling for this past 2 days.

Comment: Do i need to include any ngRoute concept, as i think i don't have to invoke the view on the basis of url.

Comment: I am not seeing any error even.

Comment: Need more information- can you post a generated version of the markup?